# how to Auto page reload in angular 7

Tags: django, angular7

Using API I fetch the data from the python framework to (Angular 7).
But when I add more values in the database than at (Angular 7) side its shows me added data when I click on refresh.
But I want to auto-reload my page when I change in the database.

Then give me some suggestion.

I have already tried the pusher in angular but it's can't work.

Comment: Add code in your question.